# Why do programs run with sudo not have system theme applied?

Tags: linux-mint, sudo, gtk

I am currently running Linux Mint 14 - Mate Version and I have noticed that whenever I run a program with sudo, the system applied GTK theme(applied in "Appearance") does not work properly. Therefore it is unavoidable in programs like synaptic which require admin rights to run. How can I fix this?

Here are two images. One of caja without sudo and one with.
[image: Caja without sudo]

[image: Caja with sudo]

Comment: Does it work if you use `gksudo` instead?

Comment: No, it does the same thing.

Comment: Thank you!!! That is it. You have been very helpful. This has been bothering me for a while!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> @MagicGuy52 - root/sudo uses the default settings (it doesn't read user GUI >prefs). Try gksudo appearance-settings (whatever it's called in mate) and change >the GUI settings for that account. – don_crissti Jun 12 at 0:08

This cool person got it.